# Eclipse -->Android Studio support jars

Tags: java, android, eclipse, git

I have a project in eclipse that I am moving to Android Studio. I did the import and then looked at my version control for deleted files and noticed these:

```
cmuench-air:POS cmuench$ git status | grep 'deleted';

deleted:    .gitignore
deleted:    .settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
deleted:    .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
deleted:    ic_launcher-web.png
deleted:    libs/android-support-v4.jar
deleted:    logo-web.png
deleted:    proguard-project.txt
deleted:    project.properties
```

The ones that stood out to me are:

- libs/android-support-v4.jar
- ic_launcher-web.png

I think the android support jar is for older platforms of android. The other one is the logo.

Why do you think these got changed?

NOTE: The path of these files did NOT change; it was a delete. (It didn't say renamed after I added it to my staging area in git.

Comment: because support libs are integrated via the support repo instead of directly as jars. If you look at your build.gradle file in your module, you'll see the `compile` command that includes the support library.

Comment: Thanks @njzk2 I found it. You can post this as and answer so I can accept.